# How to prevent duplicate tokens with same "start" & "pos" but different "end"

Tags: elasticsearch, unique, token, trim, analysis

I'm using some custom french analyzers using elisions and stopwords and snowball stemming which leads to the deletion of parts of my tokens, resulting (particularly when using ngrams or shingles) in numerous duplicate tokens having the same "start" and "pos", the same content, and differing only by "end"

Here, have an exemple, with the duplicate tokens "scandal" or "pay" having different length (end - start ) but containing the same text, and having the same "pos" and "start"
[Analyzer result exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nboTe.png)

At first I thought that a filter of type "trim" could move the "end" of the token to the actual end of the text deleting whitespaces left by deleted parts of the token, but it didn't, so I tried to use a filter with the type "unique" to remove those duplicate tokens with no luck.

Am I right to think that a "unique" type filter would only delete tokens having the same "end" (length) ? If so, how to trim/delete those duplicated tokens ? or did I made a mistake and should my solution "trip+unique" work ?

Comment: Is it possible to post your analyzer? The unique token filter should work, with the `only_on_same_position` option set to true.

Comment: `"filter":{
    "custom_unique": {
        type": "unique",
            "only_on_same_position": "true"
    }}
"analyzer": {
 "custom_french_analyzer_expr": {
  "filter": [
   "fr_stop",
   "asciifolding",
   "lowercase",
   "fr_snowball",
   "fr_elision",
   "fr_worddelimiter",
   "trim",
   "custom_unique",
   "custom_shingles"
  ],
  "charfilter": "html_strip",
  "type": "custom",
  "tokenizer": "standard"
 },
 ...
}`

Comment: Can't find out how to format the correctly with new lines when posting on stack overflow ! sorry....

Comment: Do you have a sample document that I can test?

Comment: @VincentChalmel Hey, it looks like many of your custom filters are missing from your comment. Maybe if you edited your question with all of the filters that you have made? My current guess is your elision filter is to blame.

Comment: @Andrei, Ian : OK, thanks for your interest in my issue. I will provide the full analysis with every custom token filters as soon as possible. Unfortunately I will be out of office until tuesday (Pentecost monday is a holiday here in France).

Comment: Here are all the custom filters : (part 1)
`"fr_stop": {"ignore_case": "true","type": "stop","stopwords": "_french_"},  
"fr_worddelimiter": {"type": "word_delimiter","language": "french"},  
"fr_snowball": {"type": "snowball","language": "french"},  
"custom_nGram": {"type": "ngram","min_gram": "3","max_gram": "10"},  
"custom_shingles": {"max_shingle_size": "4","min_shingle_size": "2","output_unigrams": "true","type": "shingle","filler_token": ""},  
"custom_unique": {"type": "unique","only_on_same_position": "true"},`

Comment: and the elision (part 2)`"fr_elision": {"type": "elision","articles": ["l","m","t","qu","n","s","j","d","c","jusqu","quoiqu","lorsqu","puisqu","parce qu","parcequ","entr","presqu","quelqu"]}`

Comment: @AndreiStefan ; IanGabes
Might be helpful : when adding filters one by one, the duplicates didn't appear when I added the elision but did with the stopwords filter. So I replaced the "filler_token" parameter by "*" and indeed it confirmed that those duplicates are shingles including the deleted stopwords. I thought using a space or an empty string as filler_token would deal with that... Why would elasticsearch include deleted stopwords in a shingle whithout offering the possibility to escape them ?

Comment: I found other references about this issue

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4307
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12819
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/are-these-es-bugs-or-just-wrong-implementations-by-me/27228

Comment: @VincentChalmel haven't yet looked at this in details, but I do have a question: why are you using both nGrams and shingles? It's like creating small tokens from your words and then combining and mixing up these tokens with shingles. Curious to find out why you are doing it like this.

Comment: @AndreiStefan
I don't use nGrams and Shingles for the same analyzers, for indexing and searching my texts I would only use nGrams.    
I also have fields with one or more "keywords" which combinations is important, hence I don't need nGrams on those but could benefit of shingles, and I also use shingles without nGrams to generate tokens before text-mining algorithms.

Comment: Sorry about that, haven't actually took the list of analyzers and pretty format it to see what's in there

Comment: @AndreiStefan I opened an issue in github, there you can find clean json and examples
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18391

Comment: @VincentChalmel I am stuck with the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really, somehow I don't use shingles much anymore. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your response.